# How do you define “rack awareness” in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

How do you define “rack awareness” in Hadoop?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that rack awareness means a component can actually differentiate between physical racks servers are hosted on. Link go into more depth if you're interested.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/RackAwareness.html